# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_asyncStorage.AsyncStorage.getItem')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, asyncstorage

I am working on my first react-native app and I am in the process of developing the login page. I am using AsyncStorage to remember a user's token and log them in automatically. But it does not work and I get Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_asyncStorage.AsyncStorage.getItem').
here's my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, Button,  } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faStar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function Login(props) { 

  const [ username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [ password, setPassword] = useState("")

  useEffect(()=> {
      getData();

  }, [])

  const auth = () => {
      

     fetch(`http://192.168.5.213:8000/auth/`, {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
             "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            },
         body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}),
     })
     .then( res => res.json())
     .then( res => {
        saveData(res.token)
        props.navigation.navigate("MovieList")
        
     })
     .catch( error => console.log(error))
     

     props.navigation.goBack();

  }

  const saveData = async (token)=> {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('Token', token)

  }
  const getData = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Token');
    if(token) props.navigation.navigate("MovieList")

}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.label}> Username</Text>
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Username"
        onChangeText={ text => setUsername(text) }
        value={username}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}> Password</Text>
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={ text => setPassword(text) }
        value={password}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        autoCapitalize={'none'}
        />
        <Button onPress= {() => auth()} title="Login"/>
    </View>
  );
  }

Login.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
    title: "Login",
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'orange',

    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 24,
    },
   

})


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1, 
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#282C35',
    
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "white",
    padding: 10,

  },

  input: {
    fontSize: 24,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
  },

  item: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#282C35'

  },

  itemText: {
    color:'#ffff',
    fontSize: 24,
  },

  starContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },

  orange: {
      color: 'orange',

  },

  white: {
      color: 'white',
  },

  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the default import

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage

Comment: I got "Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Failed to create storage directory.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “ExponentExperienceData” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Documents”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/itaylador/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED20E680-C5AC-4C29-8026-8EA471D69064/data/Containers/Data/Application/1065D42B-9828-4B17-93DD-57EF9F5C06BB/Documents/ExponentExperienceData, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001410540 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory"}}"

Comment: You weren't using the storage library before and now you are.

Comment: Are you using redux-persist? This error doesn't seem to be related at all to the code you posted. https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/461